# How can I update SharePoint content type properties, based on values in the document?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, excel-2010, vba

I'm using an Excel template as a custom document type in a Sharepoint Document Set.
I have some custom matadata for this document type, for instance one called Priority, which is a list (Low, Med, High).

I can read the metadata from within the document using `ActiveWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties(Property)`.

Is there any way to change the value from within the document?
I would like to have the metadata values derived from document content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refering to server metadata happens via ContentTypeProperties as you described. For them to be feched from doc content, I once created a worksheet function to do this that you tell the wanted metadata name and the value you wish it to be changed, here's my code and comments -

```
Public Function zSETSERVERMETADATA(ByVal metaTypeName As String, Optional ByVal newValue As String = "") As String
'Recalculate upon every time any cell changes
Application.Volatile
'Set wb pointer trough caller parents
Dim wb As Workbook, r As Range, ws As Worksheet
Set r = Application.Caller
Set ws = r.Parent
Set wb = ws.Parent

'Clear unused elements
Set r = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
On Error GoTo NoSuchProperty

'If value defined on newValue, set the value and showoutput
If newValue <> "" Then
    wb.ContentTypeProperties(metaTypeName).Value = newValue
    zSETSERVERMETADATA = wb.ContentTypeProperties(metaTypeName).Value
    Set wb = Nothing
    Exit Function
'If no value defined on newValue only show output but leave content type unchanged
Else
    zSETSERVERMETADATA = wb.ContentTypeProperties(metaTypeName).Value
    Set wb = Nothing
    Exit Function
End If

NoSuchProperty:
    zSETSERVERMETADATA = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    Set wb = Nothing
End Function
```

You can use it like any worksheet function for instance if you want to change server meta called "Author" to value "SickDimension" you call the function in cell with formula -

```
=zSETSERVERMETADATA("Author";"SickDimension")
```

Btw, with my function, leaving the second parameter empty will just return the value of that field.

Comment: Oh I see, ContentTypeProperties can read and set values.  Thanks, that's ace.

Comment: No problem, if I managed to answer your question, remember to mark your question answered ;)

Comment: Yes, thank you.  If you felt my question was clear, and potentially useful for others, can you upvote it.